# Can't build Ijulia in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia, conda, ijulia-notebook

After installing the latest Julia (v.1.0) package using conda, on Ubuntu v.16.04, via

```
conda install -c conda-forge julia
```

I can't seem to install IJulia. 
Thus,

```
(v1.0) pkg> add IJulia
      Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
      Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
     Resolving package versions...
     Installed VersionParsing ── v1.1.3
     Installed Conda ─────────── v1.0.2
     Installed JSON ──────────── v0.19.0
     Installed Compat ────────── v1.2.0
     Installed ZMQ ───────────── v1.0.0
     Installed IJulia ────────── v1.12.0
     Installed BinaryProvider ── v0.5.1
     Installed MbedTLS ───────── v0.6.3
     Installed SoftGlobalScope ─ v1.0.7
      Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
      [7073ff75] + IJulia v1.12.0
      Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Manifest.toml`
      [b99e7846] + BinaryProvider v0.5.1
      [34da2185] + Compat v1.2.0
      [8f4d0f93] + Conda v1.0.2
      [7073ff75] + IJulia v1.12.0
      [682c06a0] + JSON v0.19.0
      [739be429] + MbedTLS v0.6.3
      [b85f4697] + SoftGlobalScope v1.0.7
      [81def892] + VersionParsing v1.1.3
      [c2297ded] + ZMQ v1.0.0
      [2a0f44e3] + Base64 
      [ade2ca70] + Dates 
      [8bb1440f] + DelimitedFiles 
      [8ba89e20] + Distributed 
      [7b1f6079] + FileWatching 
      [b77e0a4c] + InteractiveUtils 
      [76f85450] + LibGit2 
      [8f399da3] + Libdl 
      [37e2e46d] + LinearAlgebra 
      [56ddb016] + Logging 
      [d6f4376e] + Markdown 
      [a63ad114] + Mmap 
      [44cfe95a] + Pkg 
      [de0858da] + Printf 
      [3fa0cd96] + REPL 
      [9a3f8284] + Random 
      [ea8e919c] + SHA 
      [9e88b42a] + Serialization 
      [1a1011a3] + SharedArrays 
      [6462fe0b] + Sockets 
      [2f01184e] + SparseArrays 
      [10745b16] + Statistics 
      [8dfed614] + Test 
      [cf7118a7] + UUIDs 
      [4ec0a83e] + Unicode
```

and when building, I get the following error:

```
  Building Conda ──→ `~/.julia/packages/Conda/hsaaN/deps/build.log`
  Building ZMQ ────→ `~/.julia/packages/ZMQ/ABGOx/deps/build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `ZMQ`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to open libLLVM!
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] (::getfield(BinaryProvider, Symbol("#open_libllvm#114")))() at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:649
│  [3] detect_cxx11_string_abi() at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:652
│  [4] detect_compiler_abi() at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:665
│  [5] top-level scope at none:0
│  [6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [8] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
│  [9] include(::String) at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/BinaryProvider.jl:1
│  [10] top-level scope at none:0
│  [11] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [12] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [13] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [14] top-level scope at none:2
│  [15] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
│  [16] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:389
│  [17] top-level scope at ./none:3
│ in expression starting at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:682
│ in expression starting at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/BinaryProvider.jl:12
│ ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile BinaryProvider [b99e7846-7c00-51b0-8f62-c81ae34c0232] to /home/daniel/.julia/compiled/v1.0/BinaryProvider/ek6VZ.ji.
```

which is followed by

```
Building MbedTLS → `~/.julia/packages/MbedTLS/mkHpa/deps/build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `MbedTLS`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to open libLLVM!
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] (::getfield(BinaryProvider, Symbol("#open_libllvm#114")))() at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:649
│  [3] detect_cxx11_string_abi() at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:652
│  [4] detect_compiler_abi() at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:665
│  [5] top-level scope at none:0
│  [6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [8] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
│  [9] include(::String) at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/BinaryProvider.jl:1
│  [10] top-level scope at none:0
│  [11] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [12] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [13] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [14] top-level scope at none:2
│  [15] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
│  [16] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:389
│  [17] top-level scope at ./none:3
│ in expression starting at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/PlatformNames.jl:682
│ in expression starting at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/cVlaj/src/BinaryProvider.jl:12
│ ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile BinaryProvider [b99e7846-7c00-51b0-8f62-c81ae34c0232] to /home/daniel/.julia/compiled/v1.0/BinaryProvider/ek6VZ.ji.
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
│  [2] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:313 [inlined]
│  [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1184
│  [4] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./logging.jl:311
│  [5] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:852
│  [6] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:311 [inlined]
│  [7] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:834
│  [8] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [10] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [11] include(::String) at ./client.jl:388
│  [12] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /home/daniel/.julia/packages/MbedTLS/mkHpa/deps/build.jl:1
└ @ Pkg.Operations /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/julia_1534540929950/work/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1068
  Building IJulia ─→ `~/.julia/packages/IJulia/4VL8h/deps/build.log`
```

Trying to build ZMQ or BinaryProvider separately gives the same error: that **it's unable to open libLLVM**.

I haven't encountered the problem when using older versions of Julia, neither an answer to the problem in any of the previous threads. Any ideas?

Comment: I raised a GitHub issue on https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryProvider.jl/issues/130 about this, I think it might be a bug on BinaryProvider.jl

Comment: Someone seems to have asked a duplicate question of this on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099699/unable-to-open-libllvm-on-macos-mojave (I.e. you asked it first and then they asked it again.) In addition to the GitHub issue mentioned by @sargas, see also [this one](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29720) and [this one](https://github.com/conda-forge/julia-feedstock/issues/60).

Answer (score 2):

In regards to libLLVM, check out this link [libLLVM](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/eval/index.html)

**What I would recommend: try removing those packages, adding them back, doing an update, and then resolve.**

*I am currently converting my code from Julia v0.6 to v0.7 and this is something I have had to do way too much over the last few days.*

It may also be worth it to take a look at the specific location in those files where the error is occurring.  I have a similar issue with a package and I went into the file and saw that it was testing my OS version, and I was on a non-supported version of MacOs(while unlikely to be your issue, it could be something similar).

Please let me know what happens after the steps I recommended. Good Luck!

Comment: Installing Julia from conda-forge on a new installation doesn't fix this (`docker run continuumio/anaconda /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge -yq julia && julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add(\"ZMQ\")'"`). The stack trace refers to BinaryProvider 0.5.1, but 0.4.0 is supposed to be compatible with Julia 1.0.0. Maybe a bug in the conda-forge package?