# "Unable to open libLLVM!" on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, julia, conda

I'm trying to set up Julia (v1.0.1) with Jupyter Notebooks using Anaconda on macOS (Mojave, 10.14).

I create a new conda environment, install julia via `conda install -c conda-forge julia`

In order to access Julia via jupyter notebooks I do the following:

```
using Pkg Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

The above goes well but opening Jupyter notebook and selecting Julia yields the following:

```
Blosc not installed properly, run Pkg.build("ZMQ"), restart Julia and try again
```

That's alright though - I'm missing a package. Hoping for a successful resolution of the above, I run:

```
using Pkg 
Pkg.build("ZMQ")
```

Which slaps me back with an error that I can't seem to work around:

```
Error: Error buildingZMQ: │ ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to open libLLVM!
```

Is there anything wrong with the process I'm following? It's the first time I'm trying to get Julia to work with Jupyter Notebook.

Julia info:

```
Julia Version 1.0.1 Platform Info: OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0) CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6920HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz WORD_SIZE: 64 LIBM: libopenlibm LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the XCode command line tools?

Comment: Check back [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/julia-feedstock/issues/60), [here](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryProvider.jl/issues/130), and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29720) for possible updates.